# CSS Clip-path flickers images on Google Chrome dev, text and images become blurry & displaced during animations

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-animations

Here's the page I made, and where these issues are occurring: http://archy-user.name/

The CSS: http://archy-user.name/css/style.css

Basically, this is a website I use for practicing/learning web-development related stuff.

Everything I tinker with goes into the subfolders in this website, which means the homepage was empty. Because of that, I decided to make this new homepage, although hardcoded, just so that it isn't empty...

It's technically finished.

While coding the website, I used Google Chrome Developer Edition to render the page, and just a couple of minutes ago checked how it rendered in other browsers.

**PS: THE PAGE RENDERS FLAWLESSLY, AS INTENDED, ON FIREFOX!**

There are two issues:

1. When hovering over the circles, an animation of removing the blur and increasing the clip-path size happens. Before adding blur to the code, it worked fine (when the animation only covered clip-path). Now, it works "fine", but the image boundaries flicker outside of the clip-path, in a rectangle format, as if there was no clip-path. 
   This flickering consists of "strokes" or "outlines" of the image inside the circle. If you pay attention to the flickering, you can notice the "strokes" are from the image behind the clip-path.
   **THIS ONLY HAPPENS ON GOOGLE CHROME DEVELOPER EDITION**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMJCE.png
2. When hovering over the circles, the text inside of it gets blurry and displaced for an instant, before going back to normal, happens on both chrome versions, here's what I have tried doing after some research:

   - "transform: translateZ(0)": Added to the circle, and the circle's "before" pseudo-element. It fixed the blurry text during animations, but displaces the text when actually hovering over it (the animation when hovering over the text didn't displace before adding this line), it also makes the circles flicker (unlike the first issue, this flickering occurs inside of the actual circle/clip-path, whereas the previous issue happens outside the circle/clip-path), adding the line to the text class doesn't change anything.
   - "backface-visibility": Flickers all of the circles, just like the "transform" method.
   - Also tried applying antialiasing to the text, didn't change anything.

That's what I have tried doing so far, although it wasn't much.

Though in my defense, there wasn't any variety in the answers from questions regarding the blurry text/animations, all the replies were about three methods, which I have tried all of them, and none fit the purpose (the ones that did work, created another issue)...

If I had to take I guess, it would be that I need to add "-webkit-" to some css element, considering it works fine on Firefox, but not on Chrome... Problem is, I'm not very familiar with using the webkit prefix, I'm not sure when I should, or shouldn't use it, and as most methods work fine without prefixes.

Here's how the items are formatted:

```css
.container {
  margin-top: -50px;
}

.content {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 900px;
  position: relative;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  font-family: 'Pacifico';
  font-size: 35px;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  grid-row-gap: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

.proj {
  top: 35%;
  position: relative;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.proj:hover {
  color: crimson;
  outline: 3px rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.3) solid;
  background: rgba(216, 112, 147, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4rem rgba(156, 5, 5, 0.1), 0px 0px 4rem rgba(156, 5, 5, 0.3), 0px 0px 5rem rgba(156, 5, 5, 0.3);
  -webkit-text-stroke: thin rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.circle_name {
  width: 285px;
  height: 285px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
  clip-path: circle(40%);
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.circle_name::before {
  content: '';
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background: url('https://fillmurray.com/300/300');
  background-size: cover;
  filter: blur(10px);
  transition: 0.8s;
}

.circle_name:hover,
.circle_name:hover::before {
  filter: blur(0);
  -webkit-filter: blur(0);
  clip-path: circle(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="grid">
      <!-- ALL ITEMS GO HERE -->
      <div class="circle_name">
        <span class="proj">Circle Text</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please provide code relevant to the question **in the question itself**, preferably as a [MCVE]. Links to an active site is problematic. The code there may change as you work on it and once the page is fixed, this question becomes meaningless to future users. Also on a active site we could well be dealing with a whole heap of irrelevant code.

Comment: The problem is, I don't exactly know which part of the code would be useful for me to share in order to fix the issue... But I will try adding some clarification and snippets I think are valid.

Comment: About when the problem is fixed, I will delete the link to my page, as well as to the css file, and will make a small section at the top of the post, regarding how I fixed the issue, so no worries there!

Comment: Please read the [help] and take the [tour]. Code is expected in the question itself. Make it as easy as possible for us to help you by not having to go off site, inspect page sources etc. Add the code to the question now, not once it has been solved. Specifically see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I was talking about adding the code I changed/added in order to solve the problem, not the code of the page itself... Like, if I add "x: 5" to my code and this fixes my issues, then I would add a section, explaining how I solved the problem, and create a code block including the code added/changed in order to solve the problem, which in this example would only be a line of code, containing "x: 5", so I can't add the code now, because I don't know which code it is, and that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: By the way, I added a code block at the end of the post, should be fine now, although it's not a very small code section, I can't really simplify more than this, as there are certain nuances, such as the positioning of certain elements. Though I see it as pretty readable